# Django: How to exclude a View from session creation?

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

My Django Project heavily relies on sessions, and the Framework does a very good job with this. It manages Session Cookies, the Session Database and so on, mostly done through the SessionMiddleware.

But there a some Views that explicitly do not require a session. And those Views often appear as an entry to the page.

Can I exclude these Views from the SessionMiddleware creating new sessions? If a new (anonymous) user visits such a View and leaves, there is no need for setting a Cookie or creating a database record in the sessions table.

Comment: Is the user who is visiting such a view is an authenticated user or an anonymous user?

Comment: @AKS: A session would only created for an anonymous user. An authenticated user already have a session, so I don't care if a cookie is set or not due the visit of the view. But for an anonymous user I don't want to have a new session.

Comment: You can extend the `SessionMiddleware` and override the `process_request` and `process_response` to match your usecase. In there you can compare the view name and return early without processing. Then in settings, replace the session middleware with your own.

Comment: @AKS: Already thought of that, but hoped for an easier, configuration or annotation driven way.

Comment: I am not sure there is such a way looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L12). So if you want to change the behavior, I think you will have to extend the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone the "Adapt the Middleware" way, as it looks like a session is created only on an access to the session or - in case of totally new sessions - during handling the response in the SessionMiddleware.

So I created this Middleware, that extends the `SessionMiddleware`:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.http import HttpRequest


class ConditionalSessionMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):

    def process_request(self, request: HttpRequest):
        # Default: We need a Session
        setattr(request, '_conditional_session_middleware_session_required', True)
        return super(ConditionalSessionMiddleware, self).process_request(request)

    def process_response(self, request: HttpRequest, response):
        # Is still a Session required?
        required = getattr(request, '_conditional_session_middleware_session_required', True)
        # or is the user not anonymous?
        if required or not request.user.is_anonymous:
            return super(ConditionalSessionMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)
        else:
            return response
```

To use it, I created a simple function decorator:

```
from types import MethodType


class NoSessionUsed:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.__func = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for a in args:
            if isinstance(a, HttpRequest):
                setattr(a, '_conditional_session_middleware_session_required', False)
                break
        return self.__func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance:
            return MethodType(self, instance)
        else:
            return self
```

In the class-based views, I use the decorator on the `dispatch` method:

```
@NoSessionUsed
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(MyClassBasedView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can also use it in urls.py, e.g. for Sitemaps and Feeds, where you have no direct access to the Views:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('rss.xml', NoSessionUsed(RssFeed()), name='rss'),
    path('atom.xml', NoSessionUsed(AtomFeed()), name='atom'),
    path('sitemap.xml', NoSessionUsed(views.index), {
        'sitemaps': SITEMAPS,
        'sitemap_url_name': 'sitemaps:sitemap.section'
    }, name='sitemap'),
    path('sitemaps/sitemap-<section>.xml', NoSessionUsed(views.sitemap), {
        'sitemaps': SITEMAPS
    }, name='sitemap.section'),
]
```

To activate the new Middleware, I replaced the `SessionMiddleware` in the settings.py `MIDDLEWARE` section with the new `ConditionalSessionMiddleware`.

Of course there are downsides:

- When I use sessions in the decorated view, changes will most likely not be saved
- When I use new sessions in the decorated view, the user will not get a Session Cookie

This might not be the perfect solution, but it's quite simple and works for me.